# adding File-version property to WAR file - using build.xml

Tags: java, xml

I want to add File-version property to WAR file - using build.xml.

[like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0HaG.png)

In the build.xml I have the manifest:

```
<manifest>
    <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${ant.project.name}"/>
    <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="${ba.Version.Company}" />
    <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${ba.Version.Major}.${ba.Version.Minor}.${ba.Version.Release}.${ba.Version.Build}" />
    <attribute name="Build-Timestamp" value="${current.time}"/>
</manifest>
```

But I don't know how to use it like a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `manifest` is a file resource which is stored inside your war (or jar) file.

AFAIK there is no Ant task which can configure the Windows file resources entries directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify build number as property in your build.xml file

something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Hello World Project" default="info">

   <property version="1.0"/>

   <target name="info">
      <echo>Apache Ant version is ${ant.version} - You are at ${sitename} </echo>
   </target>

</project>
```

Comment: yes, but how to add it like a property on the file? (like the image...)

Comment: There is no direct way of doing that. For doing this, you will have to extend Ant capabilities to read the file properties.  Check on how to create an Ant task here https://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html. You can create a custom task to read the version no. from file which you can later include it in your build.